# clientbase implementing more interfaces or "sub"clientbase

Tags: c#, wcf

I got two wcf services on separate servers. Both defines own clientbase like:
`public class Channel1 : ClientBase<IService1>, IService1` and
`public class Channel2 : ClientBase<IService2>, IService2`

Now I need to add them a common methods for getting service stats, lets say:
`public interface IService3{ string GetStats(); }`. On each server, there will run application (or service) which will ask for this stats

Is there a way, how can I write Channel1 and Channel2 to accept the IService3 too, so there I just define endpoint in config file? Or must I create own application for communicating with Channel1 and other for Channel2?

If I define `IService1 : IService3` and also `IService2 : IService3` and a `Channel3 : ClientBase<IService3>, IService3`, will be Channel3 able to connect to both services (one in a time on each server) depending on EndPoint? (with possibility of NotImplementedException)

My goal is to have only one application (service), which is able to call on separate Services some common methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of having both of your existing service contracts inherit a third shared contract will work as you described.  In your example, you will need to make sure IService3 is also decorated with the WCF attributes `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract`.

Comment: I finished a few minutes before whole test construction and it really works.